# Django website failing when using os.einviron.get for aws keys

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku

I am using django, aws and heroku. I have a website that goes live locally when I have the following ids set.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID","aaaa")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY","bbbb")
```

However, this is bad form because I can't commit this file to gitlab. If I did, my keys would be public (my gitlab repo isn't private yet, still practicing before I make that commitment) and all hell breaks loose. However, if I use the following code and try to go live locally

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
```

I get the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

When I use the latter code and go live via heroku as an actual webpage it works.

It's as if my `os.environ.get` command doesn't work in my local settings. Does anyone konw what to do? I'd hate to have to change these lines of code everytime I want to commit to git or push to heroku. I feel like the 2nd code should work locally, but I don't see how.

Comment: You need to set those environment variables. How are you trying to do that?

Answer (score 1):

check out [django environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ). 
It let you set all your secrets in an environment file(.env), and read in your env vars to your django application.